# How to interact with an android code using webpages?

Tags: javascript, android, binding, webview

Here is what I am doing:

I'm building a webpage which I'm going to use in [an] android [app] for [the main] UI.

I want [to] interact with the android code while working the webpage. What I need is when I click a button on the webpage on an android phone a piece of android code should get executed. Normally we use direct buttons from android but in this app I need it that way.

Please drop in any suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the documentation: [Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)